# Is there any Java ORM which return Json instead of Object?

Tags: java, json, orm

It should compatible with SQL, MySQL and oracle databases.

I have gone through a list of currently available ORM solutions [here](http://java-source.net/open-source/persistence) but didn't find which will return anything other than entity object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Hibernate,OpenJPA,Eclipse link. we can send your JSON from UI to JAVA

Answer (score 0):

If you use Mybatis you can specify a hashmap as your query type and then use a custom TypeHandler to convert from the hashmap to Json

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use Gson with Hibernate and override toString() method of your entities

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    User user=new User();
    user.setName("Test Name");
    user.setEmail("Test Email");
    System.out.println(user);

    }
```

**Output:**

{"name":"Test Name","email":"Test Email"}

```
//Entity
class User{
    private String name;
    private String email;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
    return new GsonBuilder().create().toJson(this);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

ORM is Object-Relational Mapping. So it maps to Objects. JSON on the other hand is a data format, it's usually something you convert your objects to in order to pass them outside of the Java VM.

Just retrieve the objects with an ORM and have them serialised to JSON using for example Jackson and you will get the desired result.